Change amount after initPaymentSheet but before calling confirmPaymentSheetPayment
in stripe react native, i m trying to follow the steps in  https://docs.stripe.com/payments/accept-a-payment-deferred?type=payment&integration=paymentsheet-flowcontroller
however the customer can select a payment method and then change the items which also changes the amount. how can i update the amount in the sheet since the initPaymentSheet is already called.
i tried re initPaymentSheet but that rests the payment method selected by the customer

The docs at https://docs.stripe.com/payments/accept-a-payment-deferred?platform=ios&type=payment&integration=paymentsheet-flowcontroller#update-payment-details describe using an update method, which sounds like what you're looking for?

yes it is but this is only for IOS not exposed in the react native sdk

Hmm maybe it's an oversight in Stripe's React Native wrapper? would be worth asking their support team or opening a Github issues on stripe-react-native
